# Binding applet parameters with angularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, applet

I need to pass a dynamic param to an applet.

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('jworkApp')
      .controller('AppletCtrl',['$scope', function (scope) {
              scope.base64 = "abcd";
}]);
```

This is my view, the parameter base64 is defined in the controller as "abcd"

```
<p>{{base64}}</p>
<APPLET>
  <PARAM name="text" value={{base64}} />
</APPLET>
```

When I run my page I see in the p tag the string 'abcd' , but the applet param's value it's simply "{{base64}}".

How could i fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you'd show us the rest of your code.

Comment: ok I add the controller of the view

Comment: I see a few problems there... Please refer to my working solution below.

Comment: I can see in my applet the value "{{base64}}" as param.

Comment: Did you try looking at it through Chrome Dev Tools? It sure works on my setup...

Comment: With your setup it's working :D

Comment: I thing that in my setup when the applet started the value base64 wasn't load yet.

Comment: I updated the answer, this code should work. The content of the "debug" div is the $scope.base64 variable.

Comment: The problem is not fixed. When the applet start the value in the applet is the string "{{base64}}".

Comment: What are you using the applet for? With angular you can only alter the value after the html source has been loaded.

Comment: I'm using it for sign xml

Comment: This is totally a shoot in the dark as I'm not sure about the html page and applet lifecycle, however did you try binding the whole call (e.g. value "<PARAM name="text" value="abcd" />") inside the applet tag, instead of just {{base64}}.

Comment: ...and the above solution would probably require you to use angular facilities to avoid escaping of html code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved passing the entire applet declaration. In this way it works correctly.

Controller:

```
angular.module('jworkApp')
  .controller('AppletCtrl',['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {

            $scope.b64 = 'AAAA';
            $scope.applet = 
                "<APPLET>"+
                "<PARAM name=\"testo\" VALUE=\""+$scope.b64+"\" />"+
                "</APPLET>";

             $scope.getAppletCode = function() {
                  return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.applet);
             };

  }]);
```

view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="getAppletCode()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example might be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app = "app">
<head>
    <script src = "angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<div ng-controller = "Ctrl">
    <p>{{base64}}</p>
    <APPLET>
      <PARAM id = "applet"name="{{base64}}" value="{{base64}}" />
    </APPLET>

    <div id = "debug">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.base64 = "base-sixty-four";
    }]);


    //Code to prove, that indeed, the value is what you're looking for     
    var applet = document.getElementById('applet');
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = applet.value;
</script>
</html>
```

One thing to note: since you can't see the changes on the webpage, the way to view the result is through some kind of Development Tools, such as Chrome Dev Tools, because the value has been changed by angular after the page has been loaded. This means, that simply viewing the source will not show desired results.