# Angular.js and Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, applet

I'm trying to call a java function via applet using Angular.js with no success. I'm not even getting the Applet loaded (java console is not starting when I load the app). I've used the approaches below without success. Any ideas?

[Binding applet parameters with angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973153/binding-applet-parameters-with-angularjs)

[angularjs and closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898772/angularjs-and-closing-tags)

PS: it's in Chrome and with the NPAPI enabled.

PS2: I get it with Knockout with the code below (we are migrating to Angular)

```
var res = document.getElementById("cdigApplet").signFile(file.id().toString(), "" , api.token);
```

**signFile()** is a method inside the Java Applet.

Html:

```
<applet id="cdigApplet" code="cdig.CDigApplet" archive="cdig-applet-1.0.jar, cdig-0.3.jar, json-20141113.jar" width="1" height="1" classloader_cache="false">
<param name="persistState" value="false" />
<param name="cache_option" value="no"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it even possible to call a Java method in an Applet from JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, as I've said before, I can get with the code above using Knockout instead of Angular.

Comment: @user489041  Yep.  It sure is, so long as the applet loads, the methods are public and the HTML declares the right attributes.

Comment: Show the entire HTML.  Is the applet somewhere we can visit it?  What is the URL?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've updated the post with the HTML. Thanks.

Comment: *"..with the HTML."*  I did not mean HTML snippets, I meant an entire page from `<HTML>` to `</HTML>`.  If you don't have a simple page, prepare one for testing, [validate it](https://validator.w3.org/) then post it here and let me know.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for your time man, we finally got it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got it with the code below:

index.html

```js
<script>
    <!-- applet id can be used to get a reference to the applet object -->
    var attributes = { id:'cdigApplet', code:'cdig.CDigApplet', archive:'cdig-applet-1.0.jar, cdig-0.3.jar, json-20141113.jar', width:1, height:1, classloader_cache:'false'} ;
    var parameters = {persistState: false, cache_option:'no' } ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.8');
</script>
```

signController.js

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('signController', signController);

    signController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope','listFactory', 'infoService'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function signController($rootScope, $scope, listFactory, infoService) {
        var vm = this;
        var token = $rootScope.token;
        $scope.name = infoService.getName;

        ////////////////

        $scope.signFile = function () {
            var fileId = infoService.getId();
            var Id = fileId.toString();
            var res = document.getElementById("cdigApplet").signFile(Id, '', token);            

            var json = JSON.parse(res);
            if (json.success === true)
            {
                alert("Documento assinado com sucesso! Clique em 'Abrir' para ver a assinatura.");
                $('#sign').modal('hide');
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Documento não assinado!\n" + json.message);
                $('#sign').modal('hide');
            }
        };
    }
})();
```