# java applet class not found exception in the chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

I am trying to run **Java applet** using **Google Chrome browser**. Everytime I am getting **no class found exception**. Here is my code.

HelloWorld.java

```
package my.first.pack;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2741715258812838900L;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("welcome", 150, 150);
    }

}
```

Hello.html

```
<applet code="my.first.pack.HelloWorld" width="300" height="300">
```

Comment: Have you signed your applet with code signing certificate?

Comment: Nope. How to do that?

Comment: Show the directory structure of the server containing the HTML and class file (and their locations relative to each other).  @VickyThakor alluded to something that must be fixed eventually, in that the class needs to be in a (signed) Jar these days in order to have any chance of working.  As an aside, Chrome is soon to drop all support for the NPAPI that launches (among other things) applets.  But ..

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sign your applet and all the .jar dependencies with a certificate.
2. Populate your manifest with all the tags mentioned below (it's in xml because I use maven, you can write in the way you prefer)

```xml
<codebase>http://location.of.your.jar/</codebase>
<permissions>all-permissions</permissions>
<Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>http://location.of.your.jar/</Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>
<Manifest-Version>1.0</Manifest-Version>
<Implementation-Title>App Name</Implementation-Title>
<Implementation-Version>0.1.0</Implementation-Version>
<Application-Name></Application-Name>
<Created-By>1.8.0_45</Created-By>
<Main-Class>package.YourClass</Main-Class>
<mode>development (or production)</mode>
<url>url of the application</url>
```

1. Surround your java method with the [doPrivileged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html)
2. Be sure that your browser has the java plugin enabled
3. Put your http path of your web app in the [java exception list](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml)
4. If your url has **_** (underscore/underline) probably it won't be recognized.
5. Try to move your .jar to the same folder of your html, not using the /applet folder.
6. Take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375703/angular-js-and-java-applet?noredirect=1#comment48887892_30375703), I was having a similar issue.

Remember, this error saying that 'is not a function' is because your .jar is not loading - or you made something wrong with the js syntax, what I don't think so.